# Is there a way to add a formula to unique data points in excel?

Tags: excel, validation, data-cleaning

I am trying to clean some data with this format:

A1       B1             C1
"0,1,0,E,1" "0,0,0,E"   "0,1,1,1,2,E"

[image: Raw data]

To obtain the information, I will need to sum up each cell individually, and then calculate the sum over a row.

So far, I have replaced all of the "E"s (for empty) with no data, which removed the E's, and I have replaced all of the commas with "+" signs to add the numbers in the cell. To run the formula of each cell, I will need to now place an "=" in front of each text string, however, if I copy it in with something like "="="&A1" the formula will not run because excel is reading the = as a letter or symbol and not an operator. Do you know of a way to fix this problem?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for your version ...

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<d><c>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</c><c>") & "</c></d>","//c"))
```

That's applied like below ...

[image: Formula]

... there's always someone smarter than me but that seems to work.

It’s not an in place replacement but it keeps your source data intact and provides a nice reconciliation point.

Answer (score 0):

Using a separate sheet for each column of values, given data in cell `A1` of

`0,0,0,1,0,1,1,E,1,0`

In C1, enter the formula

```
=IFERROR(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($E$14,",",""),"E",""),COLUMN()-2,1)*1, "")
```

and drag the fill handle to to the right for as many cells as the longest number of data points you have.

Enter your `SUM()`formula in `B1` (you can use the shortcut ALT + =).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this, please refer the image, where its showing as per your required output, three alternative formulas

1.) Formula used in cell B2

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(--MID($A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($A2))),1),0))
```

2.) Formula used in cell D2

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(--MID($C2,SEQUENCE(LEN($C2)),1),0))
```

The 2nd formula is applicable to Excel 2021 & O365 Users only

3.) Formula used in cell F2

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--MID($E2,ROW($1:$1000),1),0))
```

This is an array formula, so requires to press CTRL SHIFT ENTER !

[image: Three Alternative Formulas]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an update, the last formulas, which i have shared, shall work only when the digits are less than 10, however the present formula, shall work for all number of digits,

Formula used in cell B17

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(--MID(SUBSTITUTE($A17,",",REPT(" ",100)),COLUMN(A1:Z1)*99-98,100),0))
```

Please adjust your range accordingly as per your data.

[image: FORMULA TO ADD UNIQUE DATA POINTS]